# RestyGWT. How to download file from rest service?

Tags: rest, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform, resty-gwt

I would like You to ask what is the best way to download the file from server (Rest Spring Service) to the GWT Client?

As far I know I can use 2 options:

- `Window.open` (have tested)
- `iframe` (haven't tested)

For Rest asynchronous ajax calls I use `RestyGWT`, but I did not find a word about it.

I've tried `Window.open`, it worked, but when my session expires it didn't redirect to login page.

Please help.

Comment: I'm confused by your wording, are trying to go from the client to the server (e.g. To save the file)?

Comment: I've move out from this problem. I'use Window.open. But firstly I am checking is file exist and is session still valid.